# Serialize type in x64 assembly to XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a .dll that is compiled for 64bit, containing a class which I can serialize to XML. The library is compiled in Visual Studio using the "AnyCPU" flag.

I have another process that is referencing that .dll, creating an object of that type then attempting to serialize it to XML like this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(COLLADA));
using (TextWriter w = new StreamWriter(m_colladaPath, false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
serializer.Serialize(w, collada.COLLADA); //exception occurs here
}
```

This process works correctly on a 32bit machine. When attempting on a 64bit machine, the code compiles without error but at runtime I receive a "Target Invocation" error as follows:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   occurred   Message="Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an
>   invocation."   Source="mscorlib"
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments,
>   SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle
>   typeOwner)
>          at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object
>   target, Object[] arguments, Signature
>   sig, MethodAttributes
>   methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle
>   typeOwner)   InnerException:
>   **System.BadImageFormatException
>          Message="Could not load file or assembly 'goBIM_API,
>   Version=1.0.3922.23514,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt
>   was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format."**
>          Source="xnzfsdbo"
>          FileName="goBIM_API, Version=1.0.3922.23514,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
>          FusionLog=
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterCOLLADA.Write653_COLLADA(Object
>   o)
>          InnerException:

I have triple checked that everything is now compiled for AnyCPU, and have also tried compiling everything, including the library, to "x64", without success. I am not using any bit specific pointers, i.e. "IntPtr" in the library.

***UPDATE:***
I created a stand alone application using this library, created a test object and serialized it without error (all in x64). The problem seems to stem from the fact that the serialization is happening in a method called by another application. That is, the method is part of a plug-in interface for another application. Something about the application's API is messing with the serialization. The application is Autodesk's Revit. Not sure anyone here is a Revit guru?

Comment: Could you post the `COLLADA` type so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: The serializer is trying to load a 64bit assembly into a 32bit process, which ain't gonna fly.  You can turn on fusion logging on the 32bit machine to see where its picking up this assembly.  You'll need a 32bit version of the binary on the 32bit machine.  May not solve all your problems, however.  Its a first step.

Comment: @dtb he is passing this type to the XmlSerializer constructor, so I highly doubt that it is dynamic.

Comment: @Will: fusion logging? What's that?

Comment: @jdv fusion logging tracks assembly binding, the process the CLR takes trying to find a particular assembly and load it into memory.  When you need it you need it BAD.

Comment: @Will: I hope I'll never need it, but great to know it's there....

Comment: The type is huge. What's the best way to post it here?

Comment: Plus, the fusion log just tells me that it can't find the goBIM_API.dll, which seems like a junk error because again, if I remove the serialization, the code will still run with other objects created from goBIM_API.dll.

Comment: How do you create the serialization assembly? Is it created dynamically at runtime? Or do you use sgen?

Comment: Not using sgen. I believe the serialization assembly is created at runtime when you use the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like goBIM_API or one of its references are 32 bit.  If you have any assembly marked x86 it will not load into a x64 assembly.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I've checked every assembly, and used Dependency Walker to check everything is x64. Everything checks out as x64. If I take the serialization bit out of the code, the rest of the code (with other objects created from goBIM_API.dll), runs fine. It seems to be thrown only with Serialization.

Comment: @ikeo: Is goBIM_API.dll your own dll?

Comment: Definitely look at the Fusion log as suggested by the comments. It might give you more insight into where it's loading assemblies. You may be loading an assembly you are not expecting.

Comment: Yep. goBIM_API.dll is my own.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are using a third-party library (goBIM_API.dll) which is only present as a 32-bit version. You get the exception because this 32-bit assembly cannot be loaded into 64-bit process.

To fix this problem, either get a 64-bit version of that library, or, what is easier, set the target platform to x86 for all your executables.

Using x86 on a 64-bit platform usually should not have any noticeable performance hit. The only downside is that you can't get above the 2GB/3GB memory limit of a process.

**Update:**

Is AutoDesk Revit a 32-bit application? That's what it looks like. Then you will have to compile your libary using the x86 platform target to fix the error.

Comment: I've compiled a 64bit version of the library, and still get this error, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile the DLL using Multi-threaded (/MT) so that all dependencies are put in the binary of your DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Because the serializer was being called in a method called by another process, the goBIM_API.dll needed to be located in the same directory as that processes' executable. After moving the .dll to that location, serialization works fine.